# Heroku SSL certificate: change default email address

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, cname

I am trying to add an SSL certificate which I just bought to my custom domain heroku app. Right now I have www.tradespring.net CNAME'd to tradespring.herokuapp.com.

I am going through this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl
and I have reached the point of add your SSL add-on.

But it adds it to the wrong app. It adds it to one of my previous apps on a previous account which is now deleted. How do I tell it to add it to my app. When I run heroku apps it only lists one, which is the correct one.

```
alex@alex-ThinkPad-T410:~$ heroku addons:add ssl:endpoint
Adding ssl:endpoint to sharp-leaf-1669... failed
 !    App not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add the app name after the command, 
like this:

$ heroku addons:add ssl:endpoint --app tradespring